# Is there a way to tell if website is built with perl from source or anything

Tags: perl

I am just wondering , is there a way by which i could figure out if website is using perl . Like i can tell with built with that it uses wordpress or php .

Comment: Actually, you don't have to reveal your site uses PHP either.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377924/how-do-i-check-what-programming-language-a-website-is-using

Answer (score 10):

You cannot ask a web site what language it's implemented in.  There are no rules that say a ".php" URL has to be running PHP (though it probably is), that is all decided on the server side.  There's no guarantee that a site which says "Powered By Wordpress" is indeed using by Wordpress.  In general, it's poor security to give away information about your implementation details as an attacker can use that to select a known attack.

However, there's plenty of ways to guess.

One of the simplest ways to tell is to look at the URL.  Does it end in a ".pl"?  Its probably Perl (or you're looking at a Polish domain).

If you look at the response headers, sometimes the web server will clearly identify itself as using Perl.  For example, you can use `curl -I` to request just the [HTTP headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Response_message) from the server and look at the "Server" and "X-Powered-By" headers.

```
$ curl -I http://perldancer.org
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2013 05:04:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Perl Dancer 1.311
Content-Length: 19849
X-Powered-By: Perl Dancer 1.311
```

Probably using Perl.  Though again, the "Server" and "X-Powered-By" fields are purely informational and used for statistics gathering.  Basically it's bragging.  The server is not required to be telling the truth.  In fact, [it's a minor security issue that they advertise it](https://pretty-rfc.herokuapp.com/RFC2616#header.server).

If the web page identifies what technology it's using, for example http://blogs.perl.org says it's Powered By Movable Type, you can look and see if it's [written in Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_Perl#Perl_software).

Sometimes you can get hints from small details in the HTML and other content.  Sometimes they clearly state in comments what is used to output the HTML.  Sometimes you can guess based on certain form fields.  Sometimes you can tell from the cookie names and values.  Sometimes you can tell from how it creates JSON, XML, YAML or RSS output.  Sometimes the generating software will identify itself in image and PDF headers.

There are tools such as [nmap](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html) which will guess the operating system based on very small details of how it implements its networking protocols, but I don't know of such a thing for detecting the implementation language of a web site.

And, as Collin suggested, you can try to make the server spew out an error message.

But you can't ever really know.  This is the beauty of the web as a universal communication protocol, it doesn't matter what it's written in.

Answer (score 5):

Not in a general sense. If the person creating the website doesn't leak information about their implementation, you won't be able to find out.

If you can cause an error somehow, sometimes the generated error messages will give you clues to the implementation.